# Trouble Adding Publishing Action to append to an existing big query table?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

I have a dataflow flow that appends to an existing bigquery table which has been working for the last few weeks. When i run it now it gives me the error "Cannot run job. Please reload the page and try again." and won't even start the job.

After trying a lot of things, i made a copy of the flow and when the publishing action is creating a new csv file, it works but when i try to 
Add a publishing action to an existing big query table,it keeps giving me another bizarre error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0".

I have no idea what is happening since everything used to work perfectly and i made no changes whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried to check StackDriver error log to see what's in there?

Comment: sounds like a case of malformed JSON

Comment: Adding a bit more on top of previous commenters:
It might be possible that json is malformed. Dumping it to CSV might not do as strict validation as BQ does.
It might be worth checking on what JSON string caused the error.

Answer (score 1):

I am not adding anything new, but I want to give you an answer.

It seems that one of your JSON inputs may be malformed. Try logging it to see what's the problem - and also try skipping malformed JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in past comments, I suggest to check your logs in StackDriver to find out why are you getting the:

> "Cannot run job. Please reload the page and try again."

Also if you can retrieve more information about the error from those logs, It'd be useful to assist you further.

Besides the above, maybe we can solve this issue easier by only just checking the json format, [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) I put an easy third party json validator and here you can check where you have the error in your json.